# python3 pymysql fetch non-English data

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am using Python 3.4 with pymysql to load data from MySQL. The problem is I cannot retrieve non-English data. When I run the following code I get *UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 146-154: ordinal not in range(128)*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(
        ...
        charset = 'utf8',
        use_unicode = True
)

cur = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cur.execute("""SELECT ...""")

for row in cur:
        print(row['content'])
```

Then I tried to run the script with PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 and it outputs 
the mixed output:

- English characters are OK
- The series of \ud83d\udcbb similar symbols (I think they are emojis)
- And finally something like æ·³ #å®¶æ˜Ž #é£›æ©Ÿå“¥ #é¾” (should be Chinese according to MySQL Workbench)

Please advise how to fix Python encoding problem.

Comment: try without use_unicode =True

Comment: @godot, didn't help, no changes

Comment: Your error is about encoding, but you are decoding. Could you print the entire exception stack (and where do you have the error? (on `SELECT` or on `print`?) What it is the encoding of the table in the database?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode is on print

Comment: `print(row['content'].encode('utf-8', errors='backslashreplace')` (or `'ignore'`)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, non-English was replaces by \xb5\xc3\xa6\xe2\x84\xa2\xc2\xaf\xc3\xa6\xc2\xb7\xc2

Comment: So it seems not just few unicode errors but you initial string was not utf-8 (nor untf-16). Check your mysql settings (server and client side), so that you know the original encoding.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, collation on the table and on the column is utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: collation is for uniquess and sorting. Try to check what your client get. A single latin1 character (so unicode >127 and <256) could help to find out the encoding

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, the weird characters are usually within ord()>127 and ord()<256, so I have them

Comment: It do not help. For sure weird characters are in such range, but we do no know which character has which code (and for codepoint above 255 we have no idea no how many bytes are put into the string).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi and I found that the character_set of DB is latin1

Comment: Check Python notes here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Comment: `'\ud83d\udcbb'.encode('utf-16','surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')` gives `''` i.e. _Personal Computer_ emoji (`'\U0001f4bb'`).